# signed apk Parse error when parsing manifest

Tags: android, apk, android-studio, android-build, android-debug

When I try to install my signed apk I get a parse error (see logcat).
When I install the apk signed with default debug key everything is okay.

this is the logcat output:

```
08-28 17:12:47.267  23828-23828/com.android.packageinstaller W/PackageInstaller: Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation
08-28 17:12:47.267  23828-23828/com.android.packageinstaller W/PackageParser: Skipping dir: /mnt/shell/emulated/0/vertretungsplan-2.0.0.apk
08-28 17:12:47.287  23828-23828/com.android.packageinstaller D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1414K, 62% free 4110K/10772K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
08-28 17:12:47.287  23828-23828/com.android.packageinstaller I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 5.708MB for 1127536-byte allocation
```

as it says `Parse error when parsing manifest` here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="de.MayerhoferSimon.Vertretungsplan"
          android:versionCode="6"
          android:versionName="2.0.0">

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <activity
                android:name="de.MayerhoferSimon.Vertretungsplan.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="de.MayerhoferSimon.Vertretungsplan.LoginActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:noHistory="true"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>


        <!-- Settings -->
        <activity
                android:name=".Preference.Preferences"
                android:label="@string/menu_settings"
                android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value=".MainActivity" />

        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="de.MayerhoferSimon.Vertretungsplan.Preference.KlassenListPreferenceActivity"
                android:label="@string/activity_klassenList"
                android:parentActivityName=".Preference.Preferences" >
            <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value=".Preference.Preferences" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="de.MayerhoferSimon.Vertretungsplan.Preference.KLASSENLIST"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".RefreshService"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I see no things there which I should change...
My device runs 4.3
even when I change the target sdk version to 18 the error appears.

I use android studio to build and sign my apk.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

the error only appeared because I installed it from the cyanogenmod file manager.

I tried to install it from email - worked.
I tried to install it from adb - worked.

Answer (score -3):

I think your missing a

```
</activity>
```

after you second activity LoginActivity just before

```
<!-- Settings -->
```

Comment: nope, its closed in the same tag like this: `<activity android:name=".Preference.Preferences" />` when you make `/>` to close the first tag. you dont need the extra closing tag

Comment: that are called self closing tags